# Await fetch not working as expected in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Why output from code below is  `Promise {<pending>}` instead of `Response`.
What I doing wrong? Also `await fetch("https://...")` not working.

```
function asynchronousFunction() {
  return fetch("https://thatcopy.pw/catapi/rest/")
}

const mainFunction = async () => {
  const result = await asynchronousFunction()
  return result;
}
console.log(mainFunction())
```

Comment: Every async function returns a promise. You probably wrote `mainFunction` to get around this, but unfortunately this will not work.

Comment: You need to put the `console.log` *inside* the `mainFunction`. You cannot use `async`/`await` to immediately get a value from the future.

Comment: So `result = await asynchronousFunction()` get the response and then it is turn back into a promise by `async mainFunction` after return? Do I understand it correctly? ( I mean an example from my code)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't think of Promises and async functions (which return Promises) as something you can use to return a value at top-level. It's usually a bad idea that comes from the imperative and synchronous programming mindset.

Use chaining instead, either move the `console.log` inside `mainFunction`, or write this:

```
asynchronousFunction()
  .then(console.log)
```